# Iterate jQuery Object Of Arrays And Non-Arrays

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, object, multidimensional-array

consider the following...

```
var $QuestionnaireAnswers = [];

var $QuestionnaireInProgress =
        {
            Questions: {
                QuestionNumber: null,
                Options: [],
                YesNo: [],
                TextArea: []
            }
        };

function findAndRemove(array, property, value) {
   $.each(array, function(index, result) {
      if(result[property] == value) {
          //Remove from array
          array.splice(index, 1);
      }    
   });
}
```

Basically, what I have is a data-driven questionnaire that for every question number, it can have 0 or more, Options that would be a radio button list or checkboxes and 0 or more yes/no radio button groups; and or zero or more textareas...

The $QuestionnaireAnswers array is what will ultimately get posted to my mvc3 controller...

One $QuestionnaireInProgress object gets added to the $QuestionnaireAnswers array based on jquery click/change events and other criteria... for each question number.

current issue 1 is with integrating the findAndRemove function that I will use recursively to tell me if a question number exists then I will call it again and see if an item in one of the arrays that are part of the  $QuestionnaireInProgress object has a particular value in it... basically to see if a question answer has been changed or edited, like a yes/no radio has been changed or a different radio option has been selected in a radio button list, ditto for checkboxes, textarays...

current issue 2 is tweaking findAndRemove to iterate n number of arrays per question number and remove or splice it out if it exists, not quite sure of how to tweak this for this kind of recursion...

What is going on is I can't get to the point where findandremove will accept $QuestionnaireAnswers array as a parameter...

Say I add an item to it like so...

```
$QuestionnaireAnswers.push($QuestionnaireInProgress);
```

then I call `findandremove($QuestionnaireAnswers, "QuestionNumber", "1234");`

And I get the pretty much useless error of "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected.

I may be over complicating this or missing something obvious, so I appreciate any comments, suggestions etc.

thanks in advance.

Comment: For one, don't use `splice` while iterating the array in-place. Use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function instead. For the `findAndRemove` function, I'd recommend simply replacing the entire object that represents the answers for some question Y from the answers array with the fresh values. Doing a diff on exactly which values changed can get complicated and lead to unnecessary work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the console to see what line its breaking on?